# CMake compiling results in errors

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, cmake, cmake-gui

> The C compiler identification is unknown The CXX compiler
>   identification is unknown Check for working C compiler:
>   C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe Check for working C compiler:
>   C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe -- broken CMake Error at C:/Program Files
>   (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.2/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:61
>   (message):   The C compiler "C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe" is not able to
>   compile a simple test   program.
>
> It fails with the following output:
>
> Change Dir: C:/SFML-2.2/bin/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
>
> Run Build Command:"C:/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make.exe"
>   "cmTryCompileExec3616319305/fast"
>
> C:/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make.exe -f
>   CMakeFiles\cmTryCompileExec3616319305.dir\build.make
>   CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3616319305.dir/build
>
> mingw32-make.exe[1]: Entering directory
>   'C:/SFML-2.2/bin/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
>
> "C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E
>   cmake_progress_report   C:\SFML-2.2\bin\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\CMakeFiles
>   1
>
> Building C object
>   CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3616319305.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj
>
> C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -o
>   CMakeFiles\cmTryCompileExec3616319305.dir\testCCompiler.c.obj -c
>   C:\SFML-2.2\bin\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\testCCompiler.c
>
> CMakeFiles\cmTryCompileExec3616319305.dir\build.make:56: recipe for
>   target
>   'CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3616319305.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj' failed
>
> mingw32-make.exe[1]: Leaving directory
>   'C:/SFML-2.2/bin/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
>
> mingw32-make.exe[1]: ***
>   [CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3616319305.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj] Error
>   1
>
> Makefile:116: recipe for target 'cmTryCompileExec3616319305/fast'
>   failed
>
> mingw32-make.exe: *** [cmTryCompileExec3616319305/fast] Error 2
>
> CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project. Call
>   Stack (most recent call first):   CMakeLists.txt:16 (project)
>
> Configuring incomplete, errors occurred! See also
>   "C:/SFML-2.2/bin/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log". See also
>   "C:/SFML-2.2/bin/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".

---

> Compiling the C compiler identification source file
>   "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed. Compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe  Build
>   flags:  Id flags:
>
> The output was: 1
>
> Compiling the C compiler identification source file
>   "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed. Compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe  Build
>   flags:  Id flags: -c
>
> The output was: 1
>
> Compiling the C compiler identification source file
>   "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed. Compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe  Build
>   flags:  Id flags: -Aa
>
> The output was: 1
>
> Checking whether the C compiler is IAR using "" did not match "IAR .+
>   Compiler": gcc.exe: fatal error: no input files compilation
>   terminated. Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file
>   "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed. Compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/g++.exe  Build
>   flags:  Id flags:
>
> The output was: 1
>
> Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file
>   "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed. Compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/g++.exe  Build
>   flags:  Id flags: -c
>
> The output was: 1
>
> Checking whether the CXX compiler is IAR using "" did not match "IAR
>   .+ Compiler": g++.exe: fatal error: no input files compilation
>   terminated. Determining if the C compiler works failed with the
>   following output: Change Dir: C:/SFML-2.2/bin/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
>
> Run Build Command:"C:/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make.exe"
>   "cmTryCompileExec3616319305/fast" C:/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make.exe -f
>   CMakeFiles\cmTryCompileExec3616319305.dir\build.make
>   CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3616319305.dir/build
>
> mingw32-make.exe[1]: Entering directory
>   'C:/SFML-2.2/bin/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
>
> "C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_progress_report
>   C:\SFML-2.2\bin\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\CMakeFiles 1
>
> Building C object
>   CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3616319305.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj
>
> C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe    -o
>   CMakeFiles\cmTryCompileExec3616319305.dir\testCCompiler.c.obj   -c
>   C:\SFML-2.2\bin\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\testCCompiler.c
>
> CMakeFiles\cmTryCompileExec3616319305.dir\build.make:56: recipe for
>   target 'CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3616319305.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj'
>   failed
>
> mingw32-make.exe[1]: Leaving directory
>   'C:/SFML-2.2/bin/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
>
> mingw32-make.exe[1]: ***
>   [CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3616319305.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj] Error
>   1
>
> Makefile:116: recipe for target 'cmTryCompileExec3616319305/fast'
>   failed
>
> mingw32-make.exe: *** [cmTryCompileExec3616319305/fast] Error 2

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: SFML comes with binaries for every major compiler/version on all supported platforms. You don't need to rebuild it yourself with CMAKE. Just link it. Seems you don't have path to all needed toolchain executables

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question you never asked ... You don't have a compiler installed that CMake is able to find and use. Install one and try again.

Comment: How should Darh Vega ever learn to ask the right quesions when you answer them anyway?

Comment: Slowly, I guess .... He didn't ask a real question, but only an idiot wouldn't know what he was trying to ask!